# SQL Server MAXDOP , microsoft reommendation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, maxdop

Microsoft's recommendation for setting MAXDOP is based on logical processors count.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2806535

On my server which has one hex core CPU, hyper threaded,6 physical cores -> 12 logical. So by Microsoft's recommendations MAXDOP should be set to 8, however a few resources I've read say to set it to the number of physical cores , so 6 in my case, which is it ?! Or is this a question with out an answer, a depends scenario ?

Comment: Setting MAXDOP based only on MUMA nodes, cores, and logical processors is just an initial starting point.  The optimal value depends on your actual workload.

Comment: Thanks for that link Shanky, but it does go against the logical processor recommendation from MS -> Hyper threading Enabled ===> Should not exceed the number of physical processors. So in my case I should stick MAXDOP at 6 and not 8 as the MS article suggests

Comment: @davey Did you run the query to find out the result, I guess it would as well suggest 6